# Webpack hmr net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server, chunked-encoding

When it loads everything is ok and hmr is working. Then this error is appearing.

```
GET http://localhost:3000/__webpack_hmr net::ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING
```

It's like the webpackdevserver is kinda crashing then relaunch, it takes few seconds then the hmr is working again

```
[HMR] connected
```

an then 'crash' and so on ...

It seems I have this issue only in Chrome (version 55) (tested with mozilla and this problem doesn't appear).

I may have missed something in my webpack or node conf but can't find something in the doc.

Any idea how to fix this ?

//BELOW THE webpack conf

```
const path = require('path');
const merge = require('webpack-merge');
const TARGET = process.env.NODE_ENV;
process.env.BABEL_ENV = TARGET;
const webpack = require('webpack');
const NpmInstallPlugin = require('npm-install-webpack-plugin');

const PATHS =  {
    app: path.join(__dirname, 'client'),
    build: path.join(__dirname, 'build')
};

const common = {
    entry: {
        app: [PATHS.app, 'webpack-hot-middleware/client']
    },

    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },

    output: {
        path: PATHS.build,
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loaders: ['style', 'css'],
                include: PATHS.app
            },
            { 
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                loaders:['babel?cacheDirectory=true'],
                include: PATHS.app
            }
        ]   
    }
};

if(TARGET === 'dev' || ! TARGET) {
    module.exports = merge(common, {
        // devServer: {
        //  contentBase: PATHS.build,
        //  historyApiFallback: true,
        //  hot: true,
        //  inline: true,
        //  progress: true,
        //  stats: 'error-only',
        //  host: 'http://127.0.0.1/',
        //  port: 3000
        // },
        export: {
            isDev: true
        },
        plugins: [
            new webpack.optimize.OccurrenceOrderPlugin(),
            new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
            new webpack.DefinePlugin({
              'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('dev')
            }),
            new NpmInstallPlugin({
                save: true
            })
        ],
        devtool: 'eval-source-map'
    });
}

if(TARGET === "build") {
    module.exports = merge(common, {});
}
```

// Nodejs route

```
this.app.get('/', function(req,res) {
            res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './../../build/index.html'))
        })
```

// index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title> Ripple Data Analyzer</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id='root'>
        </div>
        <script src="bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

//index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './components/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: I am seeing this issue too, but I don't have an explicit server timeout.  That said, it only crashes once, and then reconnects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the real reason was that I put a setTimeout on my node server

```
server.timeout = 100;
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to update node.js to latest LTS version, because this is node bug that was fixed in version 8.1.0 (not sure about version)

`sudo s 8.9.1` (for linux)

Answer (score 1):

Guy, I suggest you update your node version, this is a problem with node [link](https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/13549)
, but to solve your problem easily, follow this steps:

`node -v
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm i n -g
sudo n stable
node -v`

See you ;)